# When I try to install Ubuntu on my laptop, already having Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, hard-drive, windows-8

When I try to install Ubuntu on my laptop, that already has Windows 8.1 pre-installed, it shows that my hard drive is empty. Could you please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you add more details? What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install, what kind of partitions did Windows create etc.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a new partition for Ubuntu to install on. You can use the partition editor GParted. 
http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

You can create a live cd and boot into that and then resize your hard drive to create a new partition. 
You can follow this step by step guide to use GParted 
http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/resizing-adding-partitions-with-gparted-live/

From there you can install Ubuntu to the new partition